# Roslyn error on script: string code = @"System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300000);";

Tags: c#, scripting, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

The following script:

```
string code = @"System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(300000);";
```

Give me errors:

```
(1,31): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
(1,31): error CS1026: ) expected
```

Code that validate:

```
public IEnumerable<Diagnostic> GetCodeErrorsAndWarnings()
{
    var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(Code);
    var diags = tree.GetDiagnostics().Where(d=>d.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Error || d.Severity == DiagnosticSeverity.Warning);
    if (diags.Any())
    {
        foreach (Diagnostic diag in diags)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(diag.ToString());
        }
        return diags;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I think `CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText` expects a class and method, at the very least? I.e. what you'd need to put in a C# file to get it to compile. You can see it's looking for the enclosing type or namespace

Comment: I 100% agree with @canton7 because that is the exact error you'll see if you try to compile something in a normal C# project with only that single line of code (and nothing around it, including a class).

Comment: If you want to parse individual statements/expressions, you may find the [scripting API](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples) more convenient.

Comment: Thanks to all, seems good. Anyone has an answer that resume you good points :-) ??? Thanks a lots!!! I will try scripting API to see if I can find an equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

canton7 had the proper answer but he did not wrote one...

The problem was that I was not using Scripting engine and instead of expecting a simple script, Roslyn expect at least a class. I wrapped my function with a class and everything compiled without error.